# combine several apoc.path.expand calls into one

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a several cypher calls that returns the count of the nodes from a specific type (`A`, `B` or `C`) that are connect to my node

```
MATCH (n {{ID:"{id}"}})
        call apoc.path.expand(n, "<", ">A", 1, 10) yield path as p
        return count(distinct nodes(p)[-1])
MATCH (n {{ID:"{id}"}})
        call apoc.path.expand(n, "<", ">B", 1, 10) yield path as p
        return count(distinct nodes(p)[-1])
MATCH (n {{ID:"{id}"}})
        call apoc.path.expand(n, "<", ">C", 1, 10) yield path as p
        return count(distinct nodes(p)[-1])
```

Making these calls 3 time is wasteful, and I wonder if I can combine them into one, but still get the distinct count for all three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this get it done for you?

```
MATCH (n {{ID:"{id}"}})
CALL apoc.path.expand(n, "<", ">A,>B,>C", 1, 10) yield path as p
RETURN labels(last(nodes(p)))[0] AS label, count(distinct nodes(p)[-1])
```